# Getting position of closest sibling on keydown

Tags: jquery, position, keydown, closest

I'm appending the results to the wrapper to see if it's getting the right positions. It works fine for the player div`(#redbox)`. However it doesn't update the closest enemy div's`(.shd)` position.

Full code here : http://jsfiddle.net/2bbW5/ Just move down and right with arrow keys and you'll see how it prints the same enemy position every time, but prints the new player position correctly each time.

```
$('.gamewrapper').on('keydown', function (event) {
        var a = event.which;
        var b = parseInt($x.css('left'), 10);
        var c = parseInt($x.css('top'), 10);
        var player_position = $('#redbox').position();
        var enemy_position = $('#redbox').siblings().closest('.shd').position();
        $('<p> Player position is : ' + player_position.left + ' and ' + player_position.top + '</p>').appendTo('.gamewrapper');
        $('<p> Enemy position is : ' + enemy_position.left + ' and ' + enemy_position.top + '</p>').appendTo('.gamewrapper');
```

What am I doing wrong in that it doesn't update the closest enemy div's position in relation to `#redbox`?

Comment: I don't think you are setting the enemy position correctly in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) won't tell you which sibling is *physically* closest to another element. You need to compute that yourself.

Here's one approach that uses `.each()` to compute and store the distance to each enemy, then `.filter()` to reduce the set of siblings to the closest enemy:

```
    var player_position = $('#redbox').position();
    var closest_dist = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY; // largest number in JavaScript
    var enemy_position = $('#redbox').siblings('.shd').each(function () {
        var epos = $(this).position();
        var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(player_position.left - epos.left, 2) + Math.pow(player_position.top - epos.top, 2)); // basic distance formula
        $(this).data('dist', dist); // easier than building an array
        closest_dist = Math.min(closest_dist, dist); // update the closest_dist variable
    }).filter(function () {
        return $(this).data('dist') - closest_dist < 0.001; // allow for floating-point errors
    }).first().position(); // use .first() since there might be more than one
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ApY46/